How to determine if $Ay>0$ has a solution?
Given a $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ as
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 &1&1&1\\
1&a_2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1&a_3&1\\
1&1&1&a_4
\end{pmatrix}$$
I would like to give a specific criterion if $Ay>0$ is solvable, where $Ay>0$ means that every entry of $Ay$ is strictly positive. I know  there ist reformulations that either this is solvable or $A^T x =0, x\geq 0, x \neq 0$. But that unfortunately did not lead anywhere.
UPDATE: I came up with the following:
If the $\text{rank}(A) < 4$ then the system is not solvable since we can perform gaussian elimination to reduce one of the rows to $0$ and $0^T y > 0$ can never be satisfied.
But this is not entirely enough since it is only necessary and not sufficient.

What exactly do you mean by $>0$? In this context, $0$ is the zero-vector, but it doesn't make sense to say a vector is greater than 0. Do you mean the vector has positive norm? Or every entry of the vector is positive? Or something else?

Hi! Thank you for your comment. I mean the inequality componentwise.

Note that $A^Tx=0, x\ge 0, x\ne 0$ is feasible iff $A^Tx=0, x\ge 0, e^Tx=1$ is feasible ($e$ is vector of ones)! Also, $A=\text{diag}(a_1-1,a_2-1,...,a_n-1)+ee^T=D+ee^T$. Therefore, using the latter feasibility problem, we must have $A^Tx=Ax=Dx+ee^Tx=Dx+e=0$, that is, we must componentwise have $(a_i-1)x_i+1=0$ for all $i\in [n]$. This further reduces to (1) for each $i\in [n]$, $-1/(a_i-1)$ must be positive (as $x\ge 0$), (2) $\sum_{i=1}^n -1/(a_i-1)=1$ (as $e^Tx=1$). So, for $i\in [n]$, $a_i$'s must be strictly smaller than $1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n -1/(a_i-1)=1$. For your case $n=4$.

Amazing, thank you!

You're welcome!
